How to view the slow log query running on aws elasti cache serverless
I am using aws elasti cache serverless and SLOWLOG command is restricted. I get an error when running
SLOWLOG GET 10
(error) ERR unknown command 'slowlog', with args beginning with: GET

How can I view the slow queries running?
